# Change node distance for particular nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How do you change the node distance to the left for a

```
 \node[state]         (q4) [below left of=q3] {$homing$};
```

Ok, it's a little bit on the left, but I want it to move it more to the left. How can I do that ?

Comment: Using the `positioning` library you can use `\node[below left = -1cm of q3] {$homing$};`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `xshift`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[state/.style={draw=red,ultra thick,rectangle,rounded corners}]

 \node[state] (q3)  {$test$}; 
 \node[state] (q4) [below left of=q3] {$homing$}; 
 \node[state] (q5) [below left of=q3,xshift=-2cm] {$homing1$}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! thx for your answer !